# React testing library - testing method is getting correct parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

How can I check to see that the right parameter is passed to a method (addTags) that is being called with in my component? AddTags is a method I have defined in a file that is imported in to my component.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), not as a screenshot.

Comment: You might be looking for the [`toHaveBeenCalledWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) matcher.